# Angular: how to handle both HTML5 mode routes and hash routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've been using the "standard" routes in Angular 1 that use the `#` sign (e.g. `/app#/home`). Now I would like to switch to the HTML5 mode to have pretty URLs (e.g.: `/app/home`).

I've toggled the HTML5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and everything is working as expected.

However, some of our users may still have bookmarks and links in email that have the old URL format and those would break. I would like to have the old URLs still work (have `/app#/home` redirect to `/app/home` automatically).

I've tried having a default route that looks at the hash like so:

```
$routeProvider
    .when({ ... })
    .otherwise({
        'controller': function($location) {
            var hash = $location.hash();
            // At this point the hash is undefined (even when there is one in the URL)
            console.log('hash = ' + hash);
//            if (hash && hash.indexOf('/') == 0) {
//                $location.path(hash);
//            } else {
//                $location.path('/home')
//            }
        }
    });
```

That unfortunately did not work (the controller doesn't see the hash and Angular seems to go in an infinite digest loop).

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: The better solution is to check whether location consists of '#'. If yes, then remove it and redirect to it.

Comment: Is there some reason for the `else` clause? If there's no hash, aren't you already where you want to be?

Comment: I actually can't even get the hash at all. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: why are you even trying to do this?  `Html5Mode` ***automatically falls back***, for browsers that don't support it.  You shouldn't have to do anything at all to continue using hash routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $routeChangeStart :

```
 angular.module('routing', ['ngRoute'])
       .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', function($rootScope, $location, $window) {
          $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", 
            (event, current, previous, rejection) => {
              if (/#\//.test($window.location.hash)) {
                 $location.path($window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
              }
          });

...
```

Comment: I tried your solution but somehow, the $routeChangeError is not fired and the code doesn't run. I also tried to put the same code with the $routeChangeStart event: code runs but $location.url() returns undefined.

Comment: I was able to tweak your code to make it work. New code is:

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next) {
    if (/#/.test($window.location.hash)) {
        $location.path($window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    }
}

If you update your answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Actually regex to only match hash starting with #/ should be /#\//.test($window.location.hash)

Comment: I was sleeping, I'll update the answer with your changes so someone can find it useful

Comment: The code has to run on $routeChangeStart rather than $routeChangeError. See the code from my previous comment.